# Remove Google Analytics tracking code from Roots wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I've inherited a wordpress site built on the Roots theme. It had two Google Analytics UA tracking snippets that appear after the closing footer tag in the homepage source.

I found and deleted one of the snippets but cannot find the origin of the remaining snippet.

Any clues from where the other UA tracking snippet is being pulled from?

My site's link is [www.mcminnlaw.com](http://www.mcminnlaw.com).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which one you removed but in lib/scripts.php there is a function defined that prints the tracking block of code named `roots_google_analytics`. My guess would be whoever built this site just included a call to this function somewhere else. Deleting this code block should cause an undefined function error that will tell you where it is being called. This is where I would start.